# Send Email using JavaScript & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, email

I am trying to send an email to myself using Ajax and PHP. The following seems to be sending the email but doesn't seem to pass the variables into PHP from Javascript.

**JavaScript**

```
    var aaa = $('#aaa').val();
    var bbb = $('#bbb').val();
    var data = 'A: ' + aaa + ' B: ' + bbb;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sendMail.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(){
    alert("Email Sent");
    }
    });
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
$subject = $_POST['data'];
mail("test@gmail.com", $subject, "", "From: info@test.com") or die("Error!");
?>
```

Could anyone please advise on how to fix this?

Comment: You need to send key-value pairs, not a string (unless you make it a real, encoded query string of course...).

Comment: "seems to" it either is, or is not. This is science, be precise

Comment: your `data` is invalid. Just give it an object. Keep it simple. Let jQuery do the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments your data variable in js is formatted the wrong way (it needs to be an object! ), you can use this one liner after defining data to convert it into the right format, as data:

```
data = { data: data };
```

this would make you not have to adjust the PHP code and populate the 'data' index in your $_POST superglobal with the string.

Comment: Why does OP not want to send this as `data: { A: aaa, B: bbb}`. I feel like you made this more complicated somehow. I think your declaration statement should read. `data = { A:aaa, B:bbb }` and his `$_POST` superglobal will have `$_POST['A']` and `$_POST['B']`, wont it?

Comment: Because what he puts into the data field goes to the $subject and actually is supposed to be used as the subject of the mail. This really just is a string.
And yes it will be exactly what you describe but then he'll have to adjust the PHP logic also.

Comment: Okay I understand now. They should probably do `data = { subject: data }` then and use `$_POST['subject']` if he wants it to be more readable. Atleast that is what I would do.

Comment: Jup better naming might be well worth the effort here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $to="123@gmail.com";
    $subject="Work Done by ";
    $subject .= $myusername;
    $headers = 'From: 456@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $messages ="test" ;
    $messages .="test1" ;
    $ret = mail($to, $subject, $messages, $headers);
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What is the problem and what is your solution?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code-only answers are not as helpful as answers that have working code plus helpful explanations. In this case, it would be worthwhile explaining why this answer to a 5 year old question is an improvement over the accepted answer.